# Avoid loops in javascript to optimise code

Tags: javascript

I have two array.

1. An array of object

   ```
   [ {id:1,name:”temp1”}, 
     {id:2,name:”temp2”}, 
     {id:3,name:”temp3”}, 
     {id:4,name:”temp4”}
   ]
   ```
2. An array

   ```
   [3,4]
   ```

I need an output

```
[ {id:3,name:”temp3”}, 
  {id:4,name:”temp4”}
]
```

Without using a loop.
Do javascript have such functions to optimise code?

Comment: What if there were such functions and they contained a loop within? How would it be any different from just writing the loop yourself? In other words, "loops are bad, remove loops" is not how you go about code optimization. You profile/benchmark the code, find the bottlenecks and _then_ think about fixing them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev does the native javascript array functions also contain loops like underscore.js array functions?

Comment: not possible without a loop (could be implicit loop without explict `for` or `while`, but in any way it's at least `O(n)` where n is number of elements in the 2nd array given it represents 1-based indexes of the 1st array and most likely `O(n*m)` otherwise)

Comment: @LabeebShareef Of course. Loop is a fundamental control-flow construct. You can't avoid it (<pedantic>except for recursion, but that's a totally different topic</pedantic>)

Comment: @Aprillion: " given it represents 1-based indexes of the 1st array" - nah, it's the ids (I think)

Comment: Yes, JavaScript has `forEach`, `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, etc. See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array Iteration Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to optimize for readability, you might use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this:

```js
const a1 = [{id:1,name:'temp1'}, {id:2,name:'temp2'}, {id:3,name:'temp3'}, {id:4,name:'temp4'}]
const a2 = [3, 4]

console.log(
  a1.filter(i => a2.includes(i.id))
)
```

P.S.: This is obviously not optimized for performance: `O(n*m)`, but the OP was asking about `native javascript array functions also contain loops` in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

*Without using a loop. Do javascript have such functions to optimise code?*

Yes, JavaScript has `forEach`, `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, etc.

From the Docs:

> ## [Array] Iteration methods
>
> Several methods take as arguments functions to be called back while processing the array. When these methods are called, the length of the array is sampled, and any element added beyond this length from within the callback is not visited. Other changes to the array (setting the value of or deleting an element) may affect the results of the operation if the method visits the changed element afterwards. While the specific behavior of these methods in such cases is well-defined, you should not rely upon it so as not to confuse others who might read your code. If you must mutate the array, copy into a new array instead.
>
> ```
> Array.prototype.entries()
> Array.prototype.every()
> Array.prototype.filter()
> Array.prototype.find()
> Array.prototype.findIndex()
> Array.prototype.forEach()
> Array.prototype.keys()
> Array.prototype.map()
> Array.prototype.reduce()
> Array.prototype.reduceRight()
> Array.prototype.some()
> Array.prototype.values()
> Array.prototype[@@iterator]()
> ```

See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array Iteration Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2)

```js
const a1 = [
   {id:1,name:'temp1'},
   {id:2,name:'temp2'},
   {id:3,name:'temp3'},
   {id:4,name:'temp4'}
];

const a2 = [3, 4];

console.log(
    a2.map( id => a1.find( _ => id == _.id) )
);
```